# List of list comparison with Dataframe columns (more than one column)

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, compare

I have a list of list like:

```
l=[['A,B,C,D', 'Z', 'category1'],
 ['A,B,C', 'Z', 'category2'],
 ['E,F,G,H', 'T', 'category4'],
 ['A,E,H', 'T', 'category4']]
```

and a DataFrame like:

```
Col1       Col2       Col3
A          Z          category1
A,B,C,D    Z          category1
E,F,G,H,I  T          category4
A,E,H      T          category4 
A,E,H      T          category5
A,E,H      U          category4
```

So I want to compare the list of list with the dataframe columns (taking all 3 columns into consideration). Comparison with loop is not working efficiently, is there a way I can make the comparison and return only matching rows from dataframe ?

```
Desired Output DataFrame:

Col1       Col2       Col3
A,B,C,D    Z          category1
A,E,H      T          category4
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What is the comparison operation? Can you explain detailed comparison process? I think that showing what you have tried by loop is very helpful(code would be best).

Comment: For example, consider `['A,B,C,D', 'Z', 'category1']`. The `'A,B,C,D'` refers to `Col1` in Dataframe, `'Z'` refers to `Col2` in Dataframe and `'category1'` refers to `Col3` in Dataframe. If all the above in list of list are equal to corresponding columns when compared, extract that row in final output. @ Boseong Choi

Comment: I think you need a logical rule for dividing columns in a list. For example, last element is `Col3`, last element of rest is `Col2`, and rest is `Col1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `DataFrame` from list and then use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with default inner join, if no parameter `on` it merge by all columns in both `DataFrame`s:

```
l=[['A,B,C,D', 'Z', 'category1'],
 ['A,B,C', 'Z', 'category2'],
 ['E,F,G,H', 'T', 'category4'],
 ['A,E,H', 'T', 'category4']]

df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['Col1','Col2','Col3']).merge(df)
print (df)
      Col1 Col2       Col3
0  A,B,C,D    Z  category1
1    A,E,H    T  category4
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look for a exact match of all 3 columns, why not try to concatenate the three columns to a fourth column:

```
df['col4']=df['col1']+df['col2']+df['col3']
```

which returns:

```
        col1 col2       col3                 col4
0          A    Z  category1          AZcategory1
1    A,B,C,D    Z  category1    A,B,C,DZcategory1
2  E,F,G,H,I    T  category4  E,F,G,H,ITcategory4
3      A,E,H    T  category4      A,E,HTcategory4
4      A,E,H    T  category5      A,E,HTcategory5
5      A,E,H    U  category4      A,E,HUcategory4
```

And you can compare 'col4' with the concatenated strings in your list `list_join`.

```
list_join=[''.join(item) for item in l]
```

which looks like:

```
['A,B,C,DZcategory1', 'A,B,CZcategory2', 'E,F,G,HTcategory4', 'A,E,HTcategory4']
```

And then merge based on the common values:

```
common =df[df['col4'].isin(list_join)]
```

The advantage is that you only have to search in a single column instead of all three, which expediates your function a lot. The disadvantage would be allows less flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

One way is using [pandas.Series.duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html?highlight=duplicated#pandas.Series.duplicated) method:

```
#df = <your DataFrame defined here>

l=[['A,B,C,D', 'Z', 'category1'],
 ['A,B,C', 'Z', 'category2'],
 ['E,F,G,H', 'T', 'category4'],
 ['A,E,H', 'T', 'category4']]

listdf=pd.DataFrame(data = l, columns=df.columns)   #transform list to dataframe
df=df.append(listdf)  #append your list to the main dataframe

duplicates=df.duplicated() # find duplicate rows; returns series of booleans

print(df[duplicates]) # print duplicate rows
```

**Output:**

```
#      Col1 Col2       Col3
#0  A,B,C,D    Z  category1
#3    A,E,H    T  category4
```